# Fail to trigger my php script when mail received by my Postfix

Tags: php, email, postfix, ubuntu-14.04

I am running Postfix mail on ubuntu 14.04.1.

I want to "trigger a PHP script when Postfix server receives a mail" After investigation and the help of many tuto, . I have configured "[postfix](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/fr/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail)" & "[Postfix virtual Aliases](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixBasicSetupHowto#Install_Postfix)" first time (I don't have deep knowledge of it) and I wrote my php code but the script output is always empty. Below all necessary file that allow you to detect my error.

**main.cf**

```
  # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = domain1.com, panawara.org, panawaredev-MS-7788, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
virtual_mailbox_domains = /etc/postfix/vhosts
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
```

**master.cf**

```
  # Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================

#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
#submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup

pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
    -o content_filter=filter:dummy

cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache

smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o content_filter=filter:dummy

#myhook    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=F user=vmail argv=/home/panawaredev/Documents/postfix.php ${sender} ${size} ${recipient}
filter    unix  -    n   n   -   -   pipe
  flags=Rq user=vmail null_sender=
  argv=/home/panawaredev/Documents/postfix.php ${sender} -- ${recipient}    
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

**postfix.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$file = fopen("postfixtest", "a");
fwrite($file, "Script successfully ran at ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n");


// read from stdin
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "first test";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $line = fread($fd, 1024);
    $email .= $line;
echo ".";
}
echo $email;
fclose($fd);

fwrite($file, $email);
fclose($file);

?>
```

**maillog file**

```
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/cleanup[10886]: 4B84620ECC: message-id=<20150412214316.4B84620ECC@localhost>
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/bounce[10891]: 3680120ECA: sender non-delivery notification: 4B84620ECC
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 4B84620ECC: from=<>, size=2234, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 3680120ECA: removed
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/local[10892]: 4B84620ECC: to=<panawaredev@panawara.org>, relay=local, delay=0.07, delays=0.03/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to maildir)
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 4B84620ECC: removed
```

**grep 3680120ECA /var/log/mail.log**

```
    panawaredev@panawaredev-MS-7788:~$ grep 3680120ECA /var/log/mail.log
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/pickup[10478]: 3680120ECA: uid=1000 from=<panawaredev>
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/cleanup[10886]: 3680120ECA: message-id=<20150412214316.3680120ECA@localhost>
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 3680120ECA: from=<panawaredev@panawara.org>, size=309, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/pipe[10888]: 3680120ECA: to=<info@domain1.com>, relay=filter, delay=0.12, delays=0.07/0/0/0.05, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (Command died with status 255: "/home/panawaredev/Documents/postfix.php". Command output: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /home/panawaredev/Documents/postfix.php on line 3 )
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/bounce[10891]: 3680120ECA: sender non-delivery notification: 4B84620ECC
Apr 12 22:43:16 panawaredev-MS-7788 postfix/qmgr[10293]: 3680120ECA: removed
```

Is this the correct way to " Trigger a PHP script when your Postfix server receives a mail " ?

If Yes , can you help me to run my script else any advice to find another way.

Comment: Thanks, but that's incomplete maillog. What's the output of `grep 3680120ECA mail.log`?

Comment: @masegaloeh, it is done. I posted for you what my maillog file display. Let me know if you want another details ( I am php developper and I am not expert in configuration of server. The more bad luck for me that I have to deal with ubuntu :3 )

Comment: Just give me any info that help me to find the output of "grep 3680120ECA mail.log?"

Comment: @masegaloeh, you have just one comment. About what second comments did you talk please !!

Comment: umm, I mean try run command `grep 3680120ECA  /var/log/mail.log` and post the output in the question :)

Comment: It is done. I have a PHP parse while I am sure my sript PHP is correct. Does Postfix need a specific annotation with PHP ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a tail -f on maillog, pipe it into your program and look for delivered statements. Then, you'll not be interfering with the system's spam filtering, and will only get solid hits. You'll also know who received the message - it's in the log file...

As for php, well, it's the wrong language for this, but your watching program can launch php to do whatever is needed there. Someone who's really clever might even be able to figure out how to harness php to do this, but, again, wouldn't be my choice.

Trying to catch mails through the mechanism you propose isn't likely to ever be made workable.

Comment: tail -f might break on logrotation, use tail -F (upper case) for that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822899/how-does-tail-f-and-logrotate-works

Comment: @DennisNolte ...Duly noted, yes. ...I don't think SADOK (the questioner) likes my answer! But I think it's simple enough and realistic. ...He's a PHP developer so if your only tool is a hammer, everything begins to look like a nail!

Comment: @Richard T sorry for being late, I had personal commitments. Finally I find the solution. Contrary to what you said, I liked your answer because it helped to find the bug. ( tail -f is all the key I to deal with server ).

I konw php can be the wrong language for this, but because of many dependencies in my project, I don't have another choice.

Comment: @SADOK ... Glad to help! ... You might give my comment an up-vote, though, if it was indeed helpful! :)

Comment: @Sorry friend I can't give you an up-vote because I have less than 15 reputation. Believe me when I reach 15 rep I will give you up-vote

Comment: @SADOK Well, I have never heard of such a thing! ...When I signed up, I guess it was early in the process and maybe we all had up-vote capability right off. . . However, I just gave your question an up-vote so maybe now you can have that ability, too!

Comment: Not yet but I consider it like the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the configuration above are correct and also the 2 tutoriels mentionned above are very useful.

The problems was caused by the permission in ubuntu.

I used "sudo":

```
sudo mail -s "hello" -a /path/file.dat info@domain1.com
content of my email is here
.
cc:
```

Then the script runned.

Comment: Ouch, this is not the solution, this is a dirty workaround.

Comment: I posted what I did to run my script with configuration above ( in the question) ... OK